# certbot is reading the wrong DNS TXT record

Tags: dns, letsencrypt

I've been trying to get Certbot to renew my wildcard certificate. I ran into a couple of wrong DNS settings at first, but after I corrected these errors, no matter what I do, Certbot seems to be reading my outdated TXT record for my acme challenge.

```
TXT _acme-challenge.domain.com mPzCnkvcka88Os2EXDOkmpo0_mNU6PW5flhouSbCQxM
TXT _acme-challenge.domain.site 1ul5coofkwYCaaOVUVuOF83VtZ1mdtpUp5apUDizrCE
```

These are the TXT records for my domains. When I try to generate the wildcard cert:

```
 certbot certonly --manual -d domain.com -d *.domain.com -d domain.site -d *.domain.site --agree-tos --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
```

I always get this **same** error:

```
- The following errors were reported by the server:

Domain: domain.com
Type:   unauthorized
Detail: Incorrect TXT record
"br9OZ2WLmKQWN3QOFaYppyzSxhkhSu7bU-ISR-kzdeY" found at
_acme-challenge.domain.com
```

The problem is that `br9OZ2WLmKQWN3QOFaYppyzSxhkhSu7bU-ISR-kzdeY` doesn't exist! It has been overwritten with a new value, but Certbot keeps reading this as the value and giving me an error.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Or is Certbot not re-reading my TXT record?

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem, but I've been using the same process for several months without any issues. I'm using DigitalOcean as my DNS provider - who are you using?